# How to compile specific Boost libraries to a DLL

Tags: c++, boost, boost-uuid

I am trying to embed the boost uuid package in my project. For ease we would like to just include some DLLs, as we do with most libraries we use. I can't figure out how to get just the DLLs for the uuid package (and any necessary dependencies). I have tried building normally, b2, bcp, and anything else I can find but all I get are copies of the source or DLLs for many of the libraries but not uuid, which is the only one I need.

In case it makes a difference, this is for a windows application. We have lots of different developers with different environments and would really just like something (like a DLL but I'm open to other options) that we can include in our source control so everyone doesn't have to install boost and set it up the same way. Ideally we would also like just boost/uuid and any dependencies, not the whole gigantic library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost uuid, like many boost libraries, is header-only: you can't find any dll because there is no dll for this library. Just copy and include the headers where you need them.

See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Configuration).

[BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) can be used to extract uuid and its dependencies.

Comment: ah... for some reason I assumed there would be other dependencies within boost that needed to be included. So I can literally just include that header file in my source with nothing else?

Comment: Typically if you look inside a boost header, you will see an absolute *shed-load* of other boost headers included (boost-pp, types, etc).  You need to copy those too - it's actually quite painful to get them all.  ... I don't think boost have an "extract this header-only library and it dependencies" feature - it would be very useful.

Comment: It has: take a look at [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I now understand what BCP was doing.